# is this a good practice when working with user profile data?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, profile

i making route for updating user profile data  i come with this solution

```
Router.route("/login").post(userController.Login);
Router.route("/register").post(userController.Register);
Router.route("/profile/update/cover").patch(userController.UpdateProfileCover);
Router.route("/profile/update/details").patch(
  userController.UpdateProfileDetails
);
Router.route("/profile/update/photo").patch(userController.UpdateProfilePhoto);
Router.route("/profile/update/email").patch(userController.UpdateProfileEmail);
Router.route("/profile/update/password").patch(
  userController.UpdateProfilePassword
);
```

the app will allow user to upload images and verfiy email and password

is this a good practice or there are alternative when it come to this type of situation

Comment: You usually have one route for updating everything or at least a few. Not one for every field.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski hmm I think what I need is just to write conditions when I receive any data and update upon it maybe one route will work well thanks konrad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically doing the following

`SELECT entity from User`  -> `Validate` -> `Update User's Entity`

On every time user is calling the API, why not adding save button to on your UI and send all changes all at once, this will help reducing queries and resources needed, this is crucial especially when you scale.

other than that it is acceptable.